# i am trying to get profile pic,email from twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter

```
public class AndroidTwitterExample extends Activity {
    private TwitterLoginButton twitterButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        setUpViews();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        twitterButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void setUpViews() {
        setUpTwitterButton();
    }

    private void setUpTwitterButton() {
        twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
        twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                String username =result.data.getUserName();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        username,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("response",result.response.getBody().toString());

                setUpViewsForTweetComposer();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setUpViewsForTweetComposer() {
        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
                .text("Just setting up my Fabric!");
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

i tried the above code but result  object i only get the username and userId how can i get profile pic and email.

Answer (score 1):

For getting profile pic use this one in success of callback :

```
   Twitter.getApiClient(result.data).getAccountService()
            .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    //If any error occurs handle it here
                }

                @Override
                public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                    //If it succeeds creating a User object from userResult.data
                    User user = userResult.data;

                    //Getting the profile image url
                    String profileImage = user.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");       

                    Log.i("profile Image",""+profileImage);

                }
            });
```

and for email Id fetching here is reference url :
    https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#request-user-email-address

Comment: it give me this exception com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required

Comment: It worked after i changed my mobile date.the mobile date was incorrect .thanks for help